# Chai is Passing the Test cases even the status is 500

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js, chai

I am running test cases for my api using chai and mocha ,chai http .I am returning response of 500 even then also my test case is getting passed

This is my test case

```
describe('/POST saveBatch', () => {
    it('it should save the Batch', (done) => {
        chai.request(app)
        .post('/batches/saveBatch')
        .set('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        .send({batch_id: 1})
        .end((err, res) => {
            expect(err).to.be.null;
           expect(res).to.have.status(200);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

And this is my controller

```
batchController.saveBatch=async(req,res)=>{
    let _value=await batchService.saveBatch(req.body);

    if(_value.error)
    {

        //throw new Error(_value.data);
      res.json({data:"Error Occurred"}).status(500);
    }

    else{
        res.json({data:"Success"}).status(200);
    }

}
```

I am returning 500 status ,but still its showing my test case to be passed.
Thanks for an help

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to use a console.log to see what's the actual value of "_value" returned from the batchService? Because I'm pretty sure your controller function doesn't actually enter your `if(_value.error)`, otherwise it would fail on `expect(res).to.have.status(200);`